# How do forks (competing chains) arise in Proof-of-Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake

I'm new to blockchain. I started with research on Bitcoin and Proof-of-Work and I think I understand that consensus mechanism. Now I wanted to continue and read some papers and FAQ's on Proof-of-Stake and the Ethereum blockchain.

What isn't clear for me (and I didn't find an answer for it yet):
While conflicting blocks (and therefore competing chains/forks) in the Bitcoin blockchain can be created because all nodes in the network validate at the same time, **how do conflicting blocks arise in the Proof-of-Stake mechanism?**

As far as I understand PoS, one single node is chosen to be the validator for the current block. The more stake a node has, the more likely is it to be chosen.

I also read about a committee of nodes and of one aggregator and many validators but I don't know if it is some Ethereum specific thing or common for PoS.